# I want to extend the quota of YouTube Data API. Is there a way to calculate the cost?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As a company, I upload multiple videos per day.

I want to increase the quota, but I can't offer it to the company because I don't know the cost.
Please tell me how to calculate the cost.
Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for your extension.  Do so early it can take a very long time to get a response for me it was three months.   Depending up on how much quota that you ask for they may ask you to pay for that.  How much you have to pay will be between you and Google there is no documentation of how much they charge for the quota for this api.